# How do I password protect WordPress user posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, passwords, posts

I'm developing a site that allows signed-in users to create blogs posts. There needs to be an option to make it either public or password protected. It's being designed to allow users to stay on the front end of the site, which is absolutely necessary. I'm currently using DJD Site Post, which gives other options for post visibility in the admin console. I'm open to any other plugin, even, as long as I can upload videos using that plugin. Any plugins, code snippets, or other items of interest I can use? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create your own module for user submitted posts? If yes, then please consider using existing plugins for the same purpose. It will cut down your work to nothing.

Visit http://wordpress.org/plugins/front-end-publishing/

This plugin provides a new front-end publishing module for registered users, you can control if the post gets published immediately or not.